# Is there a way to list COUNTIFS?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to count & calculate the sum (total quantity of all 4 words) of 4 different words in the same google sheet column. How could I just count Broccoli and Pears? [Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMM08.png)

I've been trying to find a tutorial on YouTube but haven't had success

Comment: In the example image I posted it would just be counting two words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(range,{"Broccoli","Pears"}))
```

(to be entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) if you don't have dynamic arrays)

In Sheets

```
=arrayformula(sum(countif(range,{"Broccoli","Pears"})))
```

Comment: Perfect thank you.

How could I specify a value in the same row & different column? and divide by the total count to find a percentage?

Comment: @Mason that's a new question, please post it as such (this is a Q&A site, rather than a discussion forum) and include sample data* which clarify your requirement in the context of those data, and indicate what the required result should be, based on those data.
* remember to include column headers and row numbers in any screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Check out this doc: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en.
Basically, you do `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Broccoli")`.
You can also do `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1)`, where the 2nd param, the criteria, is equal to the text content in a specific cell, A1 in the example. [This is a quick example I tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNqCm.png).